# cannot create Regular file while copying from one system to another system

Tags: linux

I tried to copy a file from one linux server  to another Linux server using the below command

```
scp sampleweb.rar pavan@50.45.555.90 /
```

It gave me this error under putty console .

```
cp: cannot create regular file `/sampleweb.rar': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/pavan@50.45.555.90': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to write to the / directory on the remote machine, it looks like you are missing a colon:

```
scp sampleweb.rar pavan@50.45.555.90:/
```

Without the colon, `scp` asssumes this is a local copy, and falls back to `cp` on the local machine, as indicated by your error messages.